# Python - Tkinter - Referencing variables in other classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a function where the user opens a dropdown menu, selects one of the answers & submits, then the program progresses to the next screen. However I am struggling with referencing the variable `maploc`

I've had to have a large play around with shortening, variable names changed, and notes removed as this is part of my A-level coursework and I would worry about it being flagged up as plagurised

**Here is my code:**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk


list1 = [
    "blah 1",
    "blah 2",
    "blah 3",
    "blah 4",
    "ect..."
]


# Define user interface Class
class class1(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        FrameManager = tkinter.Frame(self)
        FrameManager.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        FrameManager.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        FrameManager.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (class2, class3):
            frame =F(FrameManager, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(class2)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


# Define Map Choice Page Class
class class2(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.subroutine1(controller)

    def subroutine2(self, controller):
        variable1 = self.variable2.get()
        if variable1 !="":
            lambda: controller.show_frame(class3)
        else:
            pass
               
    def subroutine1(self, controller):
        variable2 = tkinter.StringVar(self)
        variable2.set(list1)
        optionmenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(self, variable2,*list1)
        optionmenu1.pack()
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(class3))
        button1.pack()


# Define Map Page Class
class class3(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.subroutine1()
    
    def subroutine1(self):
        label1 = ttk.Label(self, text = "Map page for "+ class2.subroutine2.variable1)
        label1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


# Call and run the User Interface class
class1().mainloop()
```

I am trying to reference `maploc` in the title of a separate frame, however this error is returned:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'function' object has no attribute 'variable1'
  File "C:\Users\s0101989\Downloads\snippet.py", line 65, in subroutine1
    label1 = ttk.Label(self, text = "Map page for "+ class2.subroutine2.variable1)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\s0101989\Downloads\snippet.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.subroutine1()
  File "C:\Users\s0101989\Downloads\snippet.py", line 25, in __init__
    frame =F(FrameManager, self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\s0101989\Downloads\snippet.py", line 70, in <module>
    class1().mainloop()
    ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'variable1'
```

any help please?

Comment: What is `maploc` which does not exist in your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code and I think this is because of your lack of understanding how classes work.

This is a simple example of how to create and instantiate a class and use its attributes.

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_a = 1


class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        # instantiate ClassA as class_a attribute inside ClassB
        self.class_a = ClassA()

    def print_class_a_var(self):
        # print the value of var_a, which is an attribute of class_a, which is an instance of ClassA
        print(self.class_a.var_a)


# instantiate ClassB as b
b = ClassB()

# call method "print_class_a_var" from object b
b.print_class_a_var()
```

Check out realpython.com, they have a lot of information about this topic.

[Object Oriented Programming](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/#:%7E:text=Programming%20with%20Python.-,What%20Is%20Object%2DOriented%20Programming%20in%20Python%3F,are%20bundled%20into%20individual%20objects.)